# ASP UpdateProgress control on async page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, updateprogress

I have an async page load that fetches data from an API and binds it to a repeater inside an update panel, separate to local search results.

There is a script manager in the master page.

```
<div class="searchResultContainer" runat="server" id="divApiResults">
<div class="searchResult">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpApiResults" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">

        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProgress" DisplayAfter="1000" runat="server">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <div id="lblLoadingApi" runat="server">
                        Loading...
                    </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>

            <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="label searchResultLabel" Text="EXTERNAL SEARCH RESULTS" />

            <asp:Repeater ID="rptApiResults" runat="server">
                <!-- template in here -->
            </asp:Repeater>

        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</div>
```

However, the update progress control is never shown on page load or when the repeater is sorted or the page changes. How do I get it to show "loading" until all data is loaded in the repeater?

Comment: Been a while since I've used this, try UpdateMode="Always" on your UpdatePanel and see if that works.  I tend to recall having to do that.

Comment: That didn't change anything. I did put `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` at the top of the page, added an AsyncPostBackTrigger for the repeater and now it loads the UpdateProgress when paging and sorting, just not on page load

Comment: Stepping through, it looks like all the data is bound and loaded before the page is actually shown (I guess, because the Page_Load method is async), but of course it takes a while to load all the data in, hence why I'm needing the UpdateProgress control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing things wrong. The update progress modal will never appear on an asynchronous page load, due to it being already loaded before the page has rendered. As it was posting back when it was paging and sorting that's when the UpdateProgress appeared.

My solution was load it asynchronously after the page load (as it's in an update panel it doesn't affect the rest of the page), by using a piece of jQuery to click a "trigger" button on `$(document).ready(...)`, which then went off to fetch the API results. This also set the UpdateProgress to visible which disappeared after the results had finished loading.